# Could someone explain the speed difference between the following functions?

Tags: python

The first function is a naive binary search implementation to find the square root of a number:

```
def sqrt1(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError(x)
    if x > 0:
        if x < 1:
            root = 1
            while root ** 2 > x:
                root /= 2
            half = root
            while root ** 2 != x:
                half /= 2
                diff = root + half
                if diff == root:
                    return root
                if diff ** 2 <= x:
                    root = diff
            return root
        if x > 1:
            root = 1
            while root ** 2 < x:
                root *= 2
            half = root / 2
            while root ** 2 != x:
                half /= 2
                diff = root - half
                if diff == root:
                    return root
                if diff ** 2 >= x:
                    root = diff
            return root
        return 1
    return 0
```

The second function does the same thing but is simpler and about 15 times faster than the first:

```
def sqrt2(z):
    assert z > 0
    x, y = z, None
    while x != y:
        y = x
        x = (x + z / x) / 2
    return x
```

1. Why is `sqrt2` so much faster than `sqrt1`?
2. Can `sqrt1` be made to perform more like `sqrt2`?

Comment: Erm ... just looking at the code, the fact that sqrt2 will compile into less instructions? Also, I think the algorithm you're using in sqrt1 has a slower convergence rate than the one you're using in sqrt2. Or are you trying to do bisection in both?

Comment: Just look at how many if branches there are in the two functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Binary search

Algorithm 1 does a binary search.  So if you're looking for the square root of two, you'll get the following after each iteration:

```
1.0
1.0
1.25
1.375
1.375
1.40625
1.40625
1.4140625
1.4140625
1.4140625
1.4140625
1.4140625
1.4140625
1.4141845703125
1.4141845703125
1.4141845703125
1.4141998291015625
1.41420745849609375
```

We've run 17 iterations, and we have 6 correct digits: 1.41421.  After another 17 iterations, we'll probably have around 12 correct digits.  At the 34th iteration, we get:

```
1.4142135623260401189327239990234375
```

The correct digits here are 1.414213562, so only 10 digits.

### Newton's method

The second method is Newton's method, which has quadratic convergence.  This means that you get twice as many digits for each iteration, so you'll get:

```
0   2.0
1   1.5
2   1.41666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667
5   1.41421568627450980392156862745098039215686274509803921568627
12  1.41421356237468991062629557889013491011655962211574404458491
24  1.41421356237309504880168962350253024361498192577619742849829
49  1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537723400156101
60+ 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317668
```

The left column shows the number of correct digits -- notice how it grows exponentially.  I cut off the output here, because after 7 iterations, the result is correct to the precision I chose.  (This was actually run with a higher precision datatype than Python's `float`, which can't ever give you 60 digits of precision.)

### Is it possible to make binary search faster?

No.  If you make it faster, it could not possibly be called a binary search any more.